# Global scope resolution in the presence of using namespace

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, gcc6

Consider the following code:

```
namespace foo {
  namespace bar {
    class foo {};
  }
  class baz {};
}
using namespace foo::bar;

::foo::baz mybaz;
```

Is this code valid?
Or is `::foo` ambiguous?
Or does `::foo` refer to the `class foo`, such that there is no `::foo::baz`.

When it comes to compilers, `gcc 6.1.1` seems to think the latter:

```
scope.cpp:9:8: error: ‘baz’ in ‘class foo::bar::foo’ does not name a type
 ::foo::baz mybaz;
        ^~~
```

On the other hand `gcc 5.3.1`, `clang 3.8.0`, and the intel compiler 16.0.3 do not yield any warnings or errors.

I suspect that under 3.4.3.2.2 of the C++14 standard, this should be valid and not ambiguous, but I am not quite sure.

Edit: In addition, for `foo::baz mybaz` only clang reports an ambiguous error.

Comment: Interestingly, `foo::baz mybaz` does compile in gcc as well.

Comment: Indeed, `foo::baz mybaz` is only said to be ambiguous with `clang`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[namespace.qual] is fairly straightforward:

> 1 If the *nested-name-specifier* of a *qualified-id* nominates a namespace (including the case where the *nested-name-specifier* is `::`, i.e., nominating the global namespace), the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is looked up in the scope of the namespace. The names in a *template-argument* of a *template-id* are looked up in the context in which the entire *postfix-expression* occurs.
>
> 2 For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(`X`,`m`) is defined as follows: Let S<sub>0</sub>(`X`,`m`) be the set of all declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If S<sub>0</sub>(`X`,`m`) is not empty, S(`X`,`m`) is S<sub>0</sub>(`X`,`m`); otherwise, S(`X`,`m`) is the union of S(N<sub>i</sub>,`m`) for all namespaces N<sub>i</sub> nominated by *using-directives* in `X` and its inline namespace set.
>
> 3 Given `X::m` (where `X` is a user-declared namespace), or given `::m` (where `X` is the global namespace), if S(`X`,`m`) is the empty set, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(`X`,`m`) has exactly one member, or if the context of the reference is a *using-declaration* (7.3.3), S(`X`,`m`) is the required set of declarations of `m`. Otherwise if the use of `m` is not one that allows a unique declaration to be chosen from S(`X`,`m`), the program is ill-formed.

`::foo` is a *qualified-id* with *nested-name-specifier* `::`, so the name `foo` is looked up in global scope.

S<sub>0</sub>(`::`,`foo`) contains the single declaration for `namespace foo` since there are no other declarations of `foo` in the namespace, and it has no inline namespaces. Since S<sub>0</sub>(`::`,`foo`) is not empty, S(`::`,`foo`) is S<sub>0</sub>(`::`,`foo`). (Note that since S<sub>0</sub>(`::`,`foo`) is not empty, namespaces nominated by using directives are never examined.)

Since S(`::`,`foo`) has exactly one element, that declaration is used for `::foo`.

The name `::foo::baz` is therefore a *qualified-id* with *nested-name-specifier* `::foo` that nominates a namespace. There is again a single declaration of `baz` in namespace `::foo`, so the name `::foo::baz` refers to the `class baz` declaration.

The behavior you observe in GCC 6+ is in fact a bug, filed as [GCC PR 71173](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71173).

EDIT: Lookup of `foo::baz` when it appears at global scope, a la:

```
foo::baz bang;
```

first requires a lookup of `foo` as an unqualified name. [basic.lookup.qual]/1 says this lookup only sees "namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types." [basic.scope.namespace]/1 tells us about namespace members and their scopes:

> The declarative region of a *namespace-definition* is its *namespace-body*. Entities declared in a *namespace-body* are said to be members of the namespace, and names introduced by these declarations into the declarative region of the namespace are said to be member names of the namespace. A namespace member name has namespace scope. Its potential scope includes its namespace from the name’s point of declaration onwards; and for each *using-directive* that nominates the member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that portion of the potential scope of the *using-directive* that follows the member’s point of declaration.

[basic.lookup.unqual]/4 tells us that the declaration of `namespace foo` is visible:

> A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global scope.

and para 2 says that `class foo` is also visible here:

> The declarations from the namespace nominated by a *using-directive* become visible in a namespace enclosing the *using-directive*; see 7.3.4. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules described in 3.4.1, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the *using-directive* are considered members of that enclosing namespace.

Since two declarations of different `foo` entities from differing namespaces are found, [namespace.udir]/6 tells us the use of `foo` is ill-formed:

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

Our name lookup for `foo::baz` dies before ever getting to `baz`.

Comment: My answer appears to be wrong according to the paragraph 2. Could you also elaborate on the name `foo::baz` in global namespace? It fails to compile in clang, while no diagnostic is shown by gcc.

Comment: That is indeed similar to the thoughts I had, what I am still struggling with is how `[namespace.udir]` plays into this as pointed out earlier by user2079303. Also thanks for reporting the bug.

Comment: @Zulan [namespace.udir]/6 Begins "If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different namespaces...", since lookup of either `::foo` or `::foo::baz` only finds a single declaration in a single namespace, it does not apply.

Comment: @user2079303 I'm reasonably sure `foo::baz` is ill-formed, I've added some analysis to the answer. (The unqualified lookup rules make qualified name lookup look simple - get it? "look" simple? - so I'm not as sure of my footing here.)